# Чтение бинарного файла

Tags: java

Читаю байты из бинарного файла. При считывании преобразоваю байт 0 в символ 0, байт 1 в символ 1. Но в этой строке

```
OP[i] = (char)((f1[i] == 0) ? '0' : '1');
```

возникает ошибка, компилятор говорит, что char Не может быть преобразован в String. Не понимаю, что я сделал не так. Помогите найти ошибку.

```
String OPER = "00100011101";
        byte[] bytes = new byte[OPER.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < OPER.length(); i++) {
            bytes[i] = (byte) ((OPER.charAt(i) == '0') ? 0 : 1);
            //System.out.println(bytes[i]);
        }
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("someFile.dat"))) {
            fos.write(bytes);
            fos.close();
        }

        FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream("someFile.dat");
        int size = f1.available();
        String[] OP = new String[size];
        System.out.println("Total Available Bytes: " + size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            OP[i] = (char)((f1[i] == 0) ? '0' : '1');
            System.out.print( f1.read());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, в двойные кавычки взять. Не знаю, как в Java, а в C++ строки (указатель на char) в двойных кавычках, а char - в одинарных.

Comment: Пробовал. пишет то же самое: 

`array required, but FileInputStream found
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char`

Comment: (char) тоже убери

    OP[i] = ((f1[i] == 0) ? "0" : "1");

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

```
            FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream("someFile.dat");
            int size = f1.available();
            char[] OP = new char[size];
            byte[] singleByte = new byte[1];
            System.out.println("Total Available Bytes: " + size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int readed = fi.read(singleByte)
                OP[i] = (char)((singleByte[0] == 0) ? '0' : '1');
                System.out.print( singleByte[0]);
            }
            String result = new String(OP);
```

Comment: Получилось. Но теперь эта ошибка:

`array required, but FileInputStream found`

Comment: @compl обновил

Comment: Спасибо! Но теперь компилятор пишет:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at decoder_parser.Decoder_parser.main(Decoder_parser.java:68)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: @compl блин. byte[] singleByte = new byte[1];

Очепятка

Comment: @Deadkenny, спасибо! Теперь всё работает. Только я не до конца понимаю для чего нужен readed и почему массив байтов singleByte имеет размерность 1.

Comment: @compl по-хорошему надо проверять переменную readed. Если она -1, то все из потока прочитана. А массив длиной в 1 байт потому что читаем побайьово.